# What is the best way of having a 'DataService' class that handles all connections and database updates

Tags: c#, class, dataset

I think this should be a simple thing to do, but it's doing my head in. It's a Windows Forms app in C#.

I have created a 'DataService' class that implements and fills a number of DataSets that I defined using VS's Dataset Designer.

I then pass those datasets to business objects that can display, update, add and delete rows in those datasets, then have 'DataService' handle the .AcceptChanges(). None of my tables are large.

It is working perfectly, except that updates are never being committed back to the database (MS-Access).

I have tried using 'get/set' to pass the datasets to the business classes. The datasets are being correctly updated, and I can see the updates back in the 'DataService' class in debug mode.

I've researched extensively, but most implementations with a separate data service are much more abstract than this. My idea was to only have one copy of the dataset ever instantiated, so that the DataService class would see the updates and commit them with dataset.AcceptChanges().

Of course I probably haven't implemented that correctly (even if it's a workable option), because updates don't get committed - the Access database is never updated.

In the example below, I have one Dataset dsWLQueues with two datatables. dsWLQueues was created in Dataset Designer which generates all the update etc statements...

Can someone help with my understanding?

Thanks

```
public class DataService
    {
        // Class to handle all data retrievals and management
        private static dsWLQueues dslWLQueues = new dsWLQueues();

        public static dsWLQueues Queues {get { return dslWLQueues; } set { dslWLQueues = value; dslWLQueues.AcceptChanges(); } }

        public static void LoadAllData()
        {
            dsWLQueuesTableAdapters.SongQueueNamesTableAdapter daSongQueueNames = new dsWLQueuesTableAdapters.SongQueueNamesTableAdapter();
            dslWLQueues.Clear();
            daSongQueueNames.Fill(dslWLQueues.SongQueueNames);

            dsWLQueuesTableAdapters.SongQueuesTableAdapter daSongQueues = new dsWLQueuesTableAdapters.SongQueuesTableAdapter();
            daSongQueues.Fill(dslWLQueues.SongQueues);
        }
```

Then to use this class:

```
public class QueueList : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
    {
        private dsWLQueues dsSongQueues;
        dsSongQueues = DataService.Queues;
            ...some code that displays and updates/deletes/adds data...
        DataService.Queues = dsSongQueues;
    }
```

Comment: For the update to work the OLECommand needs four queries : Select, Update, Insert Delete.  The Command Builder will take a Select Command and automatically create the other three.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

I was using DataAdapter.AcceptChanges() that only updates the in-memory dataset. I needed to use DataAdapter.Update instead.

Now the solution works perfectly. I have a DataService that loads all DataTables and makes them available via methods to all other classes.

Doh!

```
        public static DataTable Codes { get { return dtWLCodes; } }
        public static DataTable Songs { get { return dtWLSongs; } }
        public static DataTable SongLyrics { get { return dtWLSongLyrics; } }
        public static void Commit (string sTable = "")
        {
            if (sTable == "" || sTable == "Songs") { daWLSongs.Update(dslWLSongs.Songs); }
            if (sTable == "" || sTable == "SongLyrics") { daWLSongLyrics.Update(dslWLSongs.SongLyrics); }
```